# Flask record information is not saving everything

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a project using Flask. I have a route and function that is used to create a restaurant and save it in my records

The issue is that only one part of the form is being saved and the rest of the information is not being added and commited.

With the form the user submits the following information:
the restaurants table:
name
the restaurants_info table:
food_type
avg_price
city
state

the only thing that is actually being saved is the name after looking at the actual database. I was wondering why only the first add and commit is being saved in the table and the rest is not being saved in teh second table

here is the flask route code:

```
@app.route('/addrestaurant', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def CreateRestaurant():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newRestaurant = Restaurants(name = request.form['name'])
        session.add(newRestaurant)
        session.commit()
        newRestaurantInfo = Restaurants_Info(food_type = request.form['food_type'],
                                             avg_price = request.form['avg_price'],
                                             city = request.form['city'],
                                             state = request.form['state'])
        session.add(newRestaurantInfo)
        session.commit
        flash('%s was successfully created' % newRestaurant.name)
        return redirect(url_for('DisplayRestaurant'))
    else:
        return render_template('addRestaurant.html')
```

and here is the corresponding html document

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Create a new restaurant</h1>
    <h2>Please fill out the entire form</h2>

    <form action="{{url_for('CreateRestaurant')}}" method="POST">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Food Type</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="food_type"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Prices</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="avg_price"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>City</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="city"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>State</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="state"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" name="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

I just want to save the name in one table and the rest in the second table where it will be called later on

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually call `commit` the second time. Functions in Python need to be called with parens: `session.commit()`.

Note that there's no need to call it twice though; you should just do so once, after the second `add`.